# How use ' :after' selector to create a border bottom in this code

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

how to create a border bottom using pseudo selector ( :after) for this code

```
 <li class="nav-list "> 
    <a href="#" class="nav-link mr-1"> 
       <i class="fas fa-handshake"></i> loyalty Management
    </a> 
</li>
```

Comment: This is my code....<li class="nav-list "> 
   <a href="#" class="nav-link mr-1"> <i class="fas fa-handshake"></i> loyalty Management</a>
  </li>

Comment: border-bottom to what and where?

Answer (score 0):

You can use code as below:

```css
li{
position:relative;
}
.nav-list:after{
content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -4px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100vh;
    background: black;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
     <li class="nav-list "> 
        <a href="#" class="nav-link mr-1"> 
           <i class="fas fa-handshake"></i> loyalty Management
        </a> 
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: how you know it should be like that?

Comment: @Asif Ahmad that what you mean?

Comment: @לבנימלכה. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link Hope this Wil help [Codepen](https://codepen.io/asiyafatima_12/pen/GPzaZZ)

```css
.nav-list {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav-list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #000000;
}
.nav-list a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 2%;
  width: 9%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #641F5E;
}
```

```html
 <li class="nav-list "> 
    <a href="#" class="nav-link mr-1"> 
       <i class="fas fa-handshake"></i> loyalty Management
    </a> 
</li>
```